# Proof of the error bound for the midpoint rule

Tags: solution-verification, power-series, taylor-expansion

[The question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpS6A.png)

Hi everyone! I tried to solve the above question and I'm pretty confident about my current answer, but I have a feeling that I'm missing some details for my proof to be complete. I would really appreciate it if any of you have the time to check and see if I forgot anything, thank you in advance!

My solution:
We first use Taylor's theorem to find that for $x\in(\frac{h}{2}, -\frac{h}{2})$, $f(x) = f(\frac{a+b}{2}) + f'(\frac{a+b}{2})(x-\frac{a+b}{2})+R_1(x) = f(0) + f'(0)x + R_1(x)$, because $\frac{a+b}{2} = \frac{\frac{h}{2}-\frac{h}{2}}{2} = 0$ . So:
\begin{align}
    \int_{-\frac{h}{2}}^{\frac{h}{2}} f(x) \,dx &=  \int_{-\frac{h}{2}}^{\frac{h}{2}} f(0) + f'(0)x + R_1(x) \,dx \\
    &= (\frac{h}{2}--\frac{h}{2})f(0) + \int_{-\frac{h}{2}}^{\frac{h}{2}} R_1(x) \,dx\\
    &= hf(0) + \int_{-\frac{h}{2}}^{\frac{h}{2}} R_1(x) \,dx\\
\end{align}
Thus:
\begin{align}
\int_{-\frac{h}{2}}^{\frac{h}{2}} R_1(x) \,dx = \int_{-\frac{h}{2}}^{\frac{h}{2}} f(x) \,dx - hf(0)
\end{align}
We then use Taylor's inequality which says that if $M \geq |f"(x)|$ then:
\begin{align}
\int_{-\frac{h}{2}}^{\frac{h}{2}} R_1(x) \,dx &= \int_{-\frac{h}{2}}^{\frac{h}{2}} f(x) \,dx - hf(0)\\
&= |I - I_m|\\
&\leq \int_{-\frac{h}{2}}^{\frac{h}{2}} \frac{M}{2!}|x|^2 \,dx\\
&= \frac{M}{2} \left[\frac{1}{3}x^3\right]_{-\frac{h}{2}}^{\frac{h}{2}}\\
& = \frac{M}{2} * \frac{1}{3} * \frac{1}{4}h^3\\
&= \frac{M}{24}h^3
\end{align}